# How to build cordova build for black berry and IOS

Tags: blackberry, phonegap

I have learned cordova and developed android app using phonegap from [here][1] 
  [1]: http://jquerytraining.com/develop-hybrid-apps-using-cordova-cli/ but I have not getting how to make build for black berry and IOS

Answer (score 0):

Developing for these two platforms is not that straightforward as developing apps for android.

To develop and debug for Blackberry you need to install some extra SDKs like

- BlackBerry WebWorks SDK
- BlackBerry Native SDK (optional)

better read the official documentation [Blackberry](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/blackberry10/index.html).

Developing for iOS requires a paid [developer account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/how-it-works/).
and a software called Xcode.
Also look into [iOS docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html) for more details